# Vertical scrollbar issue when mouse hovers over treeview

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

I've got an issue with vertical scrolling in a `WPF` form, where `treeviews` are messing it up.

Normally if you hover over a form with a  vertical scroll bar and use your mouse wheel you can easily scroll up and down the form. This works fine, until the mouse rolls over a `treeview` in the form. Then the mouse wheel starts scrolling you up and down through the items in the `treeview` itself, and if the `treeview` doesn't have a vertical `scrollbar` then nothing happens when you spin the mouse wheel.

If you move the mouse off the `treeview` however, then the mouse wheel starts moving the vertical scroll bar like normal, until the mouse hovers over another `treeview`.

I'm wondering if there's a way to make it so that the user has to click on the `treeview` for the mouse wheel to scroll up and down there. The only thing I've found to 'fix' this problem is to set the '`IsEnabled`' property in the `treeview` to False, but that's not a viable solution because users need to be able to modify items in the `treeview`.

Comment: By chance, do you have it embedded in a separate `ScrollViewer` or are you using the one built into the template?

Comment: Yes, it looks like just about the entire form, including the treeview, is embedded inside the same ScrollViewer. The scrollviewer's XAML is this: `<ScrollViewer VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1">`

Comment: Pull it out of that ScrollViewer and use the one built into [the template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752048%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and if you read documentation on that link notice the "If the ItemsPresenter is not the direct child of the ScrollViewer, you must give the ItemsPresenter the name, ItemsPresenter." Or if you're deadset on using the external one, and it's like it is in silverlight, just adding Background="Transparent" to it will give you the hittestvisibility for the mouse wheel